# Get Couchbase background cleaner job period

Tags: couchbase

How can I access and configure the schedule period for the Couchbase (2.2.0) background job that removes expired documents (documents with expired time to live).

I know the default is 1 hour, but I can neither find where I can obtain its value from a running Couchbase server, nor how can I configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
./cbepctl localhost:11210 -b bucket_name -p bucket_password set flush_param exp_pager_stime 600
```

The Couchbase [manual](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#changing-the-disk-cleanup-interval) covers this command in more detail, please remember that this command is per a node per a bucket.

To confirm the setting you can use the `cbstats`command:

```
cbstats  localhost:11210 -b my-bucket all  | grep ep_exp_pager_stime
ep_exp_pager_stime: 600
```